# Find joint distribution for two different cases Kruskal Wallis

Tags: self-study, nonparametric, exponential-distribution, bernoulli-distribution, kruskal-wallis-test

I'm a bit stuck with my homework in a subject called "Non-parametric Statistics". The task is related to Kruskal-Wallis test.

The task is as follows:

> Let's look at the comparison of 3 independent groups, where $n_1 = n_2 = n_3 = 1 $. Find a joint distribution for ranks $R_{11}, R_{21}, R_{31}$, that is to say, a distribution of vector $(R_{11}, R_{21}, R_{31})^T$ for two different cases:
>   1) when the examined variable is from Exponential distribuiton $E(\lambda)$ in each group
>   2) when the examined variable is from Bernoulli distribution $B(p)$ in each group.

What I understand is that the solution of this task needs to be conneceted with this Kruskal-Wallis topic somehow. But I don't know exactly, how. Moreover, I'm not sure, how to start with this task. So I hope that anyone can help me out with this one. Would be very thankful!

Comment: I'd advise forgetting completely about the Kruskal-Wallis for the moment and focus on answering the question based on the details here. You appear to have three iid continuous variates. If you don't see how to write down the distribution of the set of ranks, first just write down the sample space -- what are possible observed triplets of ranks?

Comment: okay, I get it. And once I've written down the observed triplets of ranks .. then? :)

Comment: What probabilities does each triplet have?

Comment: I guess that 1/3 then?

Comment: How many possible triplets did you get?